How to search Landsat data using USGS M2M on Python based on row and path instead of a polygon area
I want to search for Landsat images via M2M API from USGS and its documentation can be found at the following link: https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/docs/json/. The entire tutorial I follow can be found here: https://code.usgs.gov/eros-user-services/machine_to_machine/m2m_landsat_bands_bundle_download/-/blob/main/M2M_Bands_Bundles_BandGroups_Download.ipynb?ref_type=heads More specifically, I want to search scenes based on tiles (path and row) instead of the polygon area. For instance, regarding product LC08_L2SP_183034_20240311_20240316_02_T1_SR_B4, the path and row info is 183034. What change should I make to the following code in order to search for it?
# spatialFilter =  {'filterType' : 'mbr',
#                     'lowerLeft' : {'latitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.miny[0],\
#                                    'longitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.minx[0]},
#                    'upperRight' : { 'latitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.maxy[0],\
#                                    'longitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.maxx[0]}}

spatialFilter = {'filterType' : 'geojson',
                 'geoJson' : {'type': 'Polygon',
                              'coordinates': [[[-148.9555, 61.4834],\
                                               [-150.9495, 61.4834],\
                                               [-150.9495, 61.0031],\
                                               [-148.9555, 61.0031],\
                                               [-148.9555, 61.4834]]]}}

search_payload = {
    'datasetName' : datasetName,
    'sceneFilter' : {
        'spatialFilter' : spatialFilter,
        'acquisitionFilter' : temporalFilter,
        'cloudCoverFilter' : cloudCoverFilter
    }
}

I have attached the entire code below.
import json
import requests
from getpass import getpass
import sys
import time
import re
import threading
import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Send http request
def sendRequest(url, data, apiKey = None, exitIfNoResponse = True):
    """
    Send a request to an M2M endpoint and returns the parsed JSON response.

    Parameters:
    endpoint_url (str): The URL of the M2M endpoint
    payload (dict): The payload to be sent with the request

    Returns:
    dict: Parsed JSON response
    """
    
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    
    if apiKey == None:
        response = requests.post(url, json_data)
    else:
        headers = {'X-Auth-Token': apiKey}              
        response = requests.post(url, json_data, headers = headers)  
    
    try:
      httpStatusCode = response.status_code 
      if response == None:
          print("No output from service")
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
      output = json.loads(response.text)
      if output['errorCode'] != None:
          print(output['errorCode'], "- ", output['errorMessage'])
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
      if  httpStatusCode == 404:
          print("404 Not Found")
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
      elif httpStatusCode == 401: 
          print("401 Unauthorized")
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
      elif httpStatusCode == 400:
          print("Error Code", httpStatusCode)
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
    except Exception as e: 
          response.close()
          print(e)
          if exitIfNoResponse: sys.exit()
          else: return False
    response.close()
    
    return output['data']

username = "xxxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxx"

print("Logging in...\n")
    
serviceUrl = "https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/api/json/stable/"
login_payload = {'username' : username, 'password' : password}
    
apiKey = sendRequest(serviceUrl + "login", login_payload)
    
print("API Key: " + apiKey + "\n")

datasetName = 'landsat_ot_c2_l2'
temporalFilter = {'start' : '2020-03-01', 'end' : '2020-03-15'}
cloudCoverFilter = {'min' : 0, 'max' : 20}

# spatialFilter =  {'filterType' : 'mbr',
#                     'lowerLeft' : {'latitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.miny[0],\
#                                    'longitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.minx[0]},
#                    'upperRight' : { 'latitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.maxy[0],\
#                                    'longitude' : aoi_geodf.bounds.maxx[0]}}

spatialFilter = {'filterType' : 'geojson',
                 'geoJson' : {'type': 'Polygon',
                              'coordinates': [[[-148.9555, 61.4834],\
                                               [-150.9495, 61.4834],\
                                               [-150.9495, 61.0031],\
                                               [-148.9555, 61.0031],\
                                               [-148.9555, 61.4834]]]}}

search_payload = {
    'datasetName' : datasetName,
    'sceneFilter' : {
        # 'spatialFilter' : spatialFilter,
        'acquisitionFilter' : temporalFilter,
        'cloudCoverFilter' : cloudCoverFilter
    }
}

scenes = sendRequest(serviceUrl + "scene-search", search_payload, apiKey)

outputs = pd.json_normalize(scenes['results'])
outputs


Maybe grid2ll method can help you?
Used to translate between known grids and coordinates.  https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/docs/reference/

Thanks! This is what I used: grid_params = {
"row": "032",
"path": "183",
"gridType": "WRS2",
"responseShape": "polygon"
}
point_grid = sendRequest(serviceUrl + "grid2ll", grid_params, apiKey)

I used this approach but the problem is that I get point_grid['coordinates'] that are the vertices of the tile. When I use the coordinates to download the tile, I get other tiles as well where there is overlap. How could I overcome it? I want to specify the tiles I download.
